# Getting following error while importing gensim package - "AttributeError: module 'numpy.random' has no attribute 'default_rng' "

Tags: python, error-handling, pycharm, package, gensim

```py
import gensim
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.../Old Files/Practice.py", line 2, in <module>
    import gensim
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs...site-packages\gensim\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from gensim import parsing, corpora, matutils, interfaces, models, similarities, utils  # noqa:F401
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs...site-packages\gensim\parsing\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .preprocessing import (remove_stopwords, strip_punctuation, strip_punctuation2,  # noqa:F401
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs...site-packages\gensim\parsing\preprocessing.py", line 26, in <module>
    from gensim import utils
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs...site-packages\gensim\utils.py", line 62, in <module>
    default_prng = np.random.default_rng()
AttributeError: module 'numpy.random' has no attribute 'default_rng'
```

Comment: This looks like a version problem.  What version of `numpy` do you have installed (`numpy.version.version`)?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using a recent version of `numpy`.

The `default_rng` method has existed since at least Numpy 1.17 - and any versions earlier than 1.17 are, as of the time of this writing in June 2021, no longer officially supported by the Numpy project: https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0029-deprecation_policy.html#support-table